# Is there a way to read and alter the contents of a huge csv file in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, large-files

I'm attempting to create a program currently that can read a csv, determine if a substring is included in one of the columns of each row, and if it isn't present, rewrites certain columns to a new csv. I have the code down for this much- but the csv I need to use the program for has well over 3 million rows. I use PyCharm and currently I'm not able to process this much data. It can only view the csv in a read-only format which doesn't allow me to use it. I know pandas has a chunk size feature but I don't know how to implement this with the rest of my code.

```
def reading(csv_input):
    originalLength = 0
    rowCount = 0
    with open(f'Web Report {csv_input}', 'w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Index', 'URL Category', 'User IP', 'URL'])
        dropCount = 0
        data = pd.read_csv(csv_input, chunksize=100000)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data,
                          columns=['Line', 'Date', 'Hour', 'User Name', 'User IP', 'Site Name',
                                   'URL Category', 'Action', 'Action Description'])
        originalLength = len(df.index)
        for line in range(originalLength):
            dataLine = df.loc[line]
            x = dataLine.get(key='Action')
            if x == 0:
                siteName = dataLine.get(key='Site Name')
                if 'dbk' in siteName:
                    dropCount = dropCount + 1
                elif 'ptc' in siteName:
                    dropCount = dropCount + 1
                elif 'wcf' in siteName:
                    dropCount = dropCount + 1
                elif 'google' in siteName:
                    dropCount = dropCount + 1
                else:
                    writer.writerow([line,  # Original Index
                                     df.loc[line].get(key='URL Category'),  # Original URL Category
                                     df.loc[line].get(key='User IP'),  # Original User IP
                                     df.loc[line].get(key='Site Name')])  # Original Site Name
                    rowCount = rowCount + 1
            else:
                dropCount = dropCount + 1
    file.close()
    print("Input: " + str(csv_input))
    print("Output: " + str(file.name))
    print("Original Length: " + str(originalLength))
    print("Current Length: " + str(rowCount))
    print("Drop Count: " + str(dropCount) + "\n")

    return df
```

Comment: have you tried using ```from functools import cache``` and ```@cache``` before your function?

Comment: if you use module `csv` to write new file then you could use the same module `csv` to read row by row - without using `pandas`

Comment: if you use `chunksize` then you get iterator which you can use with `for`-loop - like `for df in pd.read_csv(csv_input, chunksize=100000): ...code...`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `csv` to write file then you could use it also to read row by row.

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(infile)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    
    # copy headers
    headers = next(csv_reader)
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)
    
    # process rows
    for row in csv_reader:  # read row by row
        # keep only rows with even index
        if int(row[0]) % 2 == 0:
            print('--- row ---')
            print(row)
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

---

If you want to use `pandas` with `chunk` then you should use `for`-loop for this.
And when you write with pandas then you need `append` mode without headers.

```
import pandas as pd

first = True
for df in pd.read_csv('input.csv', chunksize=1):  # read row by row
    # keep only rows with even index
    if df.index % 2 == 0:
        print('--- row ---')
        print(df)
        if first:
            # create new file with headers
            df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='w')
            first = False
        else:
            # append to existing file without headers
            df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

# --- create some data ---

data = {
    'A': range(0,10), 
    'B': range(10,20),
    'C': range(20,30),
} # columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('input.csv', index=False)

# --- read and write with `pandas` ---

first = True
for df in pd.read_csv('input.csv', chunksize=1):  # read row by row
    # keep only rows with even index
    if df.index % 2 == 0:
        print('--- row ---')
        print(df)
        if first:
            # create empty with headers
            df.to_csv('output_pandas.csv', mode='w')
            first = False
        else:
            # append to existing file without headers
            df.to_csv('output_pandas.csv', mode='a', header=False)
        
# --- read and write with `csv` ---
 
with open('input.csv') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(infile)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    
    # copy headers
    headers = next(csv_reader)
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)
    
    # process rows
    for row in csv_reader:
        # keep only rows with even index
        if int(row[0]) % 2 == 0:
            print('--- row ---')
            print(row)
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

---

Doc: [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), [to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)